# .htaccess dynamic url redirecting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am having some dynamic urls when I click the link it should redirect me to the desired dynamic url (adding some changes in the current URL). I am using `.htaccess` to redirect dynamic url that start with a specific string to a `PHP` page and then redirect from there using `header()` .

PHP Part :

```
$link               = "http://date.hot.tl/aaa/bbb/ccc.html?d=1&e=2";
$subdomainSelect    = substr($link,strpos($link,"date.")+strlen("date."));
$curDate    = date('Y-m-d');
$date = new DateTime($curDate);
$date->modify('+1 day');
$tommorrow  = $date->format('Y-m-d');
$date->modify('+1 day');
$dayAfterTommorrow  = $date->format('Y-m-d');

$chkInTime          = substr($subdomainSelect,strpos($subdomainSelect,"checkin")+strlen("checkin"));
if (strpos($chkInTime,"&")) {
    $chkInTime          = substr($chkInTime,0,strpos($chkInTime,"&"));
}
$chkInTime          = trim(strip_tags($chkInTime),"=");
$chkOutTime = substr($link,strpos($link,"checkout")+strlen("checkout"));
if (strpos($chkOutTime,"&")) {
    $chkOutTime = substr($chkOutTime,0,strpos($chkOutTime,"&"));
}
$chkOutTime = trim(strip_tags($chkOutTime),"=");

if (strpos($subdomainSelect,"checkin")) {
    $subdomainSelect    = str_replace($chkInTime,$tommorrow,$subdomainSelect);      
} else {
    $subdomainSelect    = $subdomainSelect."&checkin=$tommorrow";   
}
if (strpos($subdomainSelect,"checkout")) {
    $subdomainSelect    = str_replace($chkOutTime,$dayAfterTommorrow,$subdomainSelect);
} else {
    $subdomainSelect    = $subdomainSelect."&checkout=$dayAfterTommorrow";
}
header('location:$subdomainSelect');
```

the basic idea is , when I click a link it might be dynamic so it should redirect to some dynamic URL (by making some changes in the URL using PHP) . So I create a `PHP` file to change the URL to desired one and redirect it using `header()`  this part is working fine except it does not redirect to the `PHP` page I am giving using .htaccess and also I don't know how to get the URL to my `PHP` page beacause ,

```
$link               = "http://date.hot.tl/aaa/bbb/ccc.html?d=1&e=2";
```

is a dynamic one .

.htaccess part :

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://date.hot.tl$
    RewriteRule ^index.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Does http host value really start with **http://** ?

Comment: yes , but my problem is that I am not even able to redirect some page to some page using htaccess

Comment: I think starkeen is right, %{HHTP_HOST} does not start with the protocol part *http://*

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure mod_rewrite is enabled.

Then, as starkeen already mentioned, remove the protocol part from your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^date.hot.tl(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index.php [L,R=301]
```